# Why are my divs pushing each other down?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to create a responsive design with some floating divs and stuff.
Below my header and image slider, I have a div for my main content. In here I have 2 divs, one floated left and one floated right. In the right div I have 3 divs in a single collumn. In the left div I have 4 divs all floated left, which will position them like this:

[Image - Layout OK](http://dyrfri.dk/stackoverflow/layout1.jpg)

Here is my problem - When I Resize my browser width, the two bottom divs in the left container div moves like this:

[Image - Layout NOT OK](http://dyrfri.dk/stackoverflow/layout2.jpg)

I have tried with a clearfix, but that didn't seem to solve the issue and now I am stuck.

**Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here - PLEASE! ;o)**

The screenshots above are from a Chrome browser. Any other browser (Safari, firefox, Opera) shows the same bug, but all the time. Not only when I resize to a with smaller that the page content.

I hope someone can help me out here. Getting kind of frustrated ;o(
Below, you will find my code. THANKS!

**//Jesper**

HTML:
    
        
            
                
                    Content

```
        <div id="content-wrap" class="centered">
            <div id="fp-branding-area">
                <!-- nivo slider here -->
            </div>
            <div id="content-main">
                <div class="fp-box-main">
                    <img src="images/fp_box1.jpg" alt="Alttext1">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">Caption1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="fp-box-main"><img src="images/fp_box2.jpg" alt="Alttext2">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">Caption2</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="fp-box-main"><img src="images/fp_box3.jpg" alt="Alttext3">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">Caption3</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="fp-box-main"><img src="images/fp_box4.jpg" alt="Alttext4">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">Caption4</h1>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /end #content-main -->
            <div id="content-side">
                <div class="fp-box-side">
                    <img src="images/fp_box_side1.jpg" alt="Side Alttext1">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">SideCaption1</h1>   
                </div>
                <div class="fp-box-side">
                    <img src="images/fp_box_side2.jpg" alt="Side Alttext2">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">SideCaption2</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="fp-box-side">
                    <img src="images/fp_box_side3.jpg" alt="Side Alttext3">
                    <h1 class="box-caption">SideCaption3</h1>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /end #content-side -->
        </div> <!-- /end #content-wrap -->
    </div> <!-- /end #page -->

    <footer id="footer-main">
        <div id="footer-wrap" class="centered">
            Content
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, hgroup {
  font-family: Avenir;
  font-size: 1.18em;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.centered {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-width {
  width: 960px;
}

#page {
  background: url(../images/gradient_page.png) repeat-x;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-main {
  height: 137px;
  background: url(../images/bg_header.jpg);
}

#header-wrap {
  width: 960px;
}

#content-wrap {
  background: url(../images/web-dropshadow_header.png) center top no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 136px;
  /* must be same height as the footer */
}

#fp-branding-area {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2.11361%;
  background-color: #c6c6c6;
}

#content-main {
  width: 78.85416666666667%;
  /* ((757 / 960) * 100) */
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 2.11361%;
}

#content-side {
  width: 21.14583333333333%;
  /* ((203 / 960) * 100) */
  float: left;
}

.fp-box-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 47.88639%;
  /* ((362.5 / 757) * 100) */
  margin: 2.11361% 2.11361% 0 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: none;
}

.fp-box-main img, .fp-box-side img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.fp-box-side {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 7.88177%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.fp-box-side h1 {
  font-size: .8em;
}

.box-caption {
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#footer-main {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -136px;
  /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 136px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: white;
}

#footer-wrap {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: have you thought about using a css framework?

Comment: I have thought about it. However, I like to know what's in my css and why it's there. I have used a style reset, but that's about it.

Comment: Actually, I just tried it. A very nead tool. However, it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since all 4 pictures are floated left, the resizing will affect them, even if you give their **parent div** a bigger **width** they will float on 1 line.

Inside the **left div**, create 2 normal **divs**, in the first div, put a floating left image, and a floating right image, and in the second div do the same thing.

```
-----------------------------------------
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
-----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
|               |      |                |
-----------------------------------------
```

It would be better as well if you give the left div and the divs inside it a minimum width.

```
min-width:100px;
```

**UPDATE: Another possible solution**

If the maximum `width` of your page is `960px;` give the **Left Parent Div** a `min-width:500px;` and the **Right Parent Div** a `min-width:400px;` this way, when you re-size, they will maintain a fixed width and will not get smaller, means they will not affect the order of the floated elements inside of them.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested. However, it did not solve the issue. Any other suggestions? ;o(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the parent of about 1000px and give width in pixel so that when you resize or zoom in or zoom out, you can avoid these kind of situation.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want it in pixels. I want it to be nice and flexible with percentages and em's ;o)

Answer (score 0):

the problem of you is the percent unit's and margin.

the true way to make responsive design with percent is don't use 'margin' when you use margin you make mistake with 0.01 percent wrong make fall of all your layout. you need to make it with wrappers and 'padding'.

now when you use padding you can do this

```
* {
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
}
```

this peace of code make all of your page to inside padding is mean when you make box with 50% and put 50% padding the padding is calculate from the inside of the box. and the you can make the percent calculate without fear about wrong 0.01 percent.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this before and it's usually something to do with height, even if it is off by 1px it will display wrongly like in layout 2. This is because all boxes are floating to the left and if it hits another box it will continue on a new line.

I would suggest try playing around with setting a definitive height to your boxes rather than auto and see if that fixes it.

Hope this helps